# How to share Network tab of chrome to different users, realtime?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge-extension

Looking forward to a free or commercial solution:

1. During a web page presentation, QA, back-end and front-end
   developers need to view network traffic, while scenario is being
   played in browser.
2. With a motto to identify problematic server (Http Api) calls. which
   breaks a page.
3. All network tab history becomes available to all parties realtime.

> Looking forward to a solution to sync this history across multiple
>   users. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Chrome's remote debugging or you could also develop an extension which will intercept all the networks activity from a browser (The browser/s where the "scenario" is being played needs to have this Extension installed). You can then send this network activity to remote host. You can even create a webpage to view the network activity from any machine.

Chrome extensions have ability to view internet traffic. Use the chrome.webRequest API to observe and analyze traffic and to intercept, block, or modify requests in-flight. You can read more about this here ::: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

There is also a good article which can clear any doubts if you have regarding this ::: https://medium.com/@gilfink/adding-web-interception-abilities-to-your-chrome-extension-fb42366df425

Answer (score -2):

At present, There is no any inbuilt feature available to share the network tab of chrome, FireFox or Edge in real time.

There are some extensions are available in chrome store to sharing the Tab.

You can try to make a test with those and check whether it shows the development tools when you share the tab with other users.

if it works then it can solve your issue.

Otherwise you can try to use calling apps like Skype or Microsoft Teams. with the help of that you can share your desktop or any specific window for example Chrome window to other users in a conference call.

Regards

Deepak